# Connecting react to firestore

Tags: reactjs, express, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning to develop a website with Firestore as database, but not sure which architecture to use.

1. Using the web-client sdk and communicate directly with Firestore from react?
2. Setting up a express server with the admin sdk and call the express server from the react app, check if authenticated, and communicate with Firestore?

Is there any advantages using one or the other?

Have I understood it correctly, or is it only the web-client sdk I should use, and the admin sdk only if I want to develop a dashboard to control usage off the app?

Comment: Your choice of application architecture is really up to you, based on the needs of your application.  It's not necessarily better to use one or the other.  You actually have a bewildering number of choices, especially if your app requires a backend.

Comment: I'm developing a blog from scratch. I want one user to be able to create blogposts, and everyone else to just read or comment.

Comment: What would the advantages of #2 be in your opinion? Because that's what should drive your decision.

Comment: I'm trying to find any advantages, but none really stand out. Just thinking if I later want to add more features like sending emails or creating an admin dashboard, but some may be resolved with cloud functions.